# Jquery accordion and Galleria JS image viewer issues

Tags: jquery, galleria

I am currently making a web portfolio for myself and I rant into a bit of a problem with the accordion.

currently I initialize the accordion this way:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
         active: false,
         autoHeight: false,
         navigation: true,
         collapsible: true
    });
});
```

This works perfectly however I'm using the Galleria JS image viewer ([www.Galleria.io](http://www.Galleria.io)) which must be initialized as well for each project of mine. The problem is that because the accordion contents are hidden, the image viewer experiences initialization errors.

I was told that I have to place the Galleria element outside of the viewport or change the way the accordion works. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve my problem?

Comment: Please post a link to the accordion plugin, a jsFiddle example or some other code that explains how the accordion works.

Comment: sorry about that. To clarify the accordion is the standard jquery ui accordion. I didn't modify it much besides css and the options shown above on initialization. link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialize Galleria in the accordion change event handler instead of onload:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change

**Update:**

Version 1.2.7, currently in beta, let’s you set a **wait** option. This allows you to tell Galleria how long to wait until the gallery can extract computed measurements before initializing.

Setting `wait:true` should do the trick, it will then wait for infinity (or until the gallery is visible using user interaction).

Download the beta at github: https://github.com/aino/galleria

Wait option docs: https://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/docs/options/wait.rst